# Parse database javascript "OR" query

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm using Parse backend for my javascript application.
It's for a shop and the cashier will need to scan a QR code, then a list of products on that card will load.
I want to load the information from every product on that card.
I get that with different queries and then 1 mainQuery to get them.
I'm testing with 3 products, now I'm doing this:

```
var mainQuery = Parse.Query.or(queries[0], queries[1], queries[2]);
```

I set the queries with a for loop but this line above me needs to be flexible. Now it's just for 3 products. The ideal thing to do would be:

```
var mainQuery = Parse.Query.or(queries);
```

Just giving all the queries at once... but this doesn't work..
Is there any solution to get this to work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Function.prototype.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Comment: Or with ES6 spread syntax: `Parse.Query.or(...queries);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know `parse.com` at all, but to generalize this as a pure javascript answer any function which takes multiple parameters can be called with `apply` and an array

```js
function doSomething(arg1, arg2, arg3){
    console.log(arg1,arg2,arg3);
}

var arr = ["val1","val2","val3"]
doSomething.apply(this, arr);
```

So, in your question you can *probably* do this:

```
var mainQuery = Parse.Query.or.apply(Parse.Query,queries);
```

There is an even easier way to do this in ES6, using the spread syntax

```
var mainQuery = Parse.Query.or(...queries);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ES6 [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```
var mainQuery = Parse.Query.or(...queries);
```